# How to control fetch-size of Expo-AV Video component?

Tags: react-native, expo, video-streaming, fetch-api

As i tested (by the network tab in debugger), if `<Video/>` takes `source={uri}`, it will not download whole file at begining, but will simply download a part of it, so basically using HTTP `content-range` header realted stuff.
Its very cool, to have that, but i would like to create something like TikTok/Instagram clone, and for that i would like to **control how big part of video will be downloaded first**. So basically:

- Download first ~5 seconds of video
- If user won't stop watching it (by scrolling to another video) download the rest of the video
  This way I will save bandwith and mobile data transfer of user.

So **how to control  how big part of video is going to be downloaded by Expo-AV `<Video/>` component?**

I tried to use Expo-FileSystem to asynchronously download part of video file, but i dont really know where to go from there. Should i convert it to blob? And if so, what to do next?

**Update**
I did not managed to fetch it neither purely with Expo-AV  headers option, neither by downloadAsync, neither as an Asset or as an AVPlaybackSource. I just couldn't do it.
The last attempt i did ([all code from this attempt is here, on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/mxSTxea0)) was close one, but for some reason, after calling a function that would fetch another range of data, it just stops the player for some reason...

Can someone help me, please? Its very strange that after so many years of react-native/expo development there is no tool to download video by parts, or to tell how big part of video should be downloaded...

Comment: Hi. You'll get faster help if you tell us the **codec** / **format** of the video bytes  that you're dealing with. Also browser features can affect playback. Your testing options are different `IF iPhone/Safari` versus `IF Windows/Firefox` ... Anyways typically: **(1)** The first chunk which should always contain the video's header part. **(2)** After downloading, use MediaSource to [feed the chunk](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+mediasource+appendbuffer) into the video decoder (`<video>` tag). **(3)** Make sure each chunk starts at the beginning of a frame (including frame headers).